# Published or Release Build for Node.js

Tags: node.js, compilation

Are there any npm packages for converting node.js source code with all its dependencies within node_modules folder to compiled/released/published build files
like for example :

- .net has .dll file
- java has .jar file
- elixir has .beam file.

Comment: Have you looked at Webpack?

Comment: just to clarify what I am asking is convertion of  node.js codebase to IL like rest for aforementioned technologies(.ddl,.jar, .beam) rather than just "bundling" it

Comment: I'm removing the java, .net and elixir tags from this question. While you mention them they're not really germane to the question.

Comment: Minifying CSS and js files using grunt/gulp and deploy these files

Comment: it is not about minifying, it is more on the lines of code conversion from base native to IL

Answer (score 0):

I think [WebAssembly](http://webassembly.org/) may be along the lines of what you're asking for. Also see this [blog post](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/what-is-webassembly-the-dawn-of-a-new-era-61256ec5a8f6) for a bit more on the subject.